# Google Cloud Platform / Amazon Web Services multithreading on virtual cores

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for information but after reading google's doc about [thread management](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager) i didn't reach the whole info i need such as following example:

Assuming that vcores of GCP/AWS are physical threads each one, virtualized so you can scale threads as vcores when needed. As if you make a PHP app on it, and if you've 4 cores, your app will attend 4 requests at a time

**(tell me if i'm wrong on any assumption, please, i really want to understand it well).**

So i was asking myself what happens if you create a new thread on a java application. It will scale GCP or AWS adding a new core for a little time, or it will be managed without adding extra-cost for the app?

If it works as the multi-threading that you can perform on local machine, i may have misunderstood how this virtual cores are working.

If it's the second case and it increases the cloud hosting amount, where can i see how many $ it will add to the invoice to evaluate it? It's the same price that you add when upgrading with 1 extra vcore? (i saw the thread limit for a request is 50, which seems excessive for a single request).

If that's another case, please tell me, i'm over-informed (methods, apis, etc) but without getting the correct answers for my doubts.

The use case is that we have a php service which takes loads of requests so i don't know if it's better to split it into micro-services deployed on different instances to set each instance with required vcores, or translate this service to java using multi-threading.

Thanks a lot, sincerelly

Answer (score 0):

> The use case is that we have a php service which takes loads of requests

I am not sure understanding the backend mechanism of virtual infrastructure that forms the core of GCP/AWS will help here. Each cloud provider use a different hardware with different multi/hyper threading configuration. If its a heavy service use the machine type that has high vCPU throughput.

> so i don't know if it's better to split it into micro-services

Difficult to comment on whether it can be split or not. Its not an implementation choice but a design choice. IMO If all services are to be run at the same time then no point running microservices.

Comment: This is not the question, i'll decide to split it or not, and i know each provider offers their own implementation but, as i saw last year using GCP and AWS both implements same features with same approach with different names on loads of things. I'm asking on both because i can move the project to one or another indistinctly. 
So i need to know how it works in backend and pricing to make a decision. The software is irrelevant here, imagine an API that gives you random cat pics. it matters how many requests can handle at a time and the cost ($) of handling those requests.